# Navigate to home page if url pattern match

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a home url like **https://abe.com** and now I have a scenario like below
If I get url like **https://abe.com/en/test/test1** I should allow
and If I get like **https://abe.com/en/test/test1/test2** , needs to redirect to home page

I am trying something like below but not working.

location ~* ^/test/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+) {
proxy_pass http://${home};
}

Comment: Redirect to home page should use `return 301 /;` and not a `proxy_pass`.

Comment: I used return 301 , but still same issue. it seems issue is with regExp  ~* ^/test/([a-z]+)/?$/([a-z]+)/?$

Comment: I do not understand your regular expession, why is there a `?$` in the middle of it?

Comment: regular expression corrected. it should be like Test-url and regExp is  ([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)

Comment: According to your examples, the URI begins with `/en/` and the regular expression only matches URIs that begin with `/test/`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`^/test/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)`
To:
`/test/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)`

At least for me it fixed your issue. I verified it with regex builder. Because with ^ you only match url's that start with /test/, which isn't the case.